# Split string into list, but two words in quotation mark as one?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to make my own little console in Python3 and I'm trying to split my given commands.

For example:

> mkdir dir becomes arg[0] = mkdir, arg[1] = dir

I know i can do that with args.split(' '), but I'm trying to make it so that anything in quotation becomes one argument.

For example:

> mkdir "New Folder" becomes arg[0] = mkdir, arg[1] = New Folder.

Comment: Argparse lib should do the job : https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following using `shlex`:

```
import shlex
res = shlex.split('mkdir "New Folder"')
print(res)
# ['mkdir', 'New Folder']
```

Another option using `re`:

```
import re
[p for p in re.split("( |\\\".*?\\\"|'.*?')", 'mkdir "New Folder"') if p.strip()]
# ['mkdir', '"New Folder"']
```

Or:

```
import re
res3 = re.findall("(?:\".*?\"|\S)+", 'mkdir "New Folder"')
print(res3)
# ['mkdir', '"New Folder"']
```

Other option using `csv`:

```
import csv
res4 = list(csv.reader(['mkdir "New Folder"'], delimiter=' '))[0]
print(res4)
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
def splitArgsIntoArguments(args):
    result = args.split(' ')
    i = 0
    length = len(result)
    while i <  length:
        if result[i][0] == '"':
            # Trim string
            result[i] = result[i][1:]
            # Then for each next element merge it with result[i] until it ends with '"'
            for j in range(i+1 , len(result)):
                stop = False
                if result[j][-1] == '"':
                    # Trim string
                    result[j] = result[j][0:-1]
                    stop = True
                result[i] += " " + result[j]
                # Remove the jth element from the list
                result = result[0:j] + result[j+1:]
                # Then substract one from the length to not get out of range error
                length -= 1
                if stop: break
        i += 1

    return result
```

It's a bit ugly, but the function goes through each argument in the result list and if it starts with '"' it merges all elements to the right of it until it finds one that ends with '"'.